# Reload properties from Spring

Tags: java, spring

Inside the xml

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.properties</value>
        <value>WEB-INF/classes/myProperties.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How do I refresh the properties of all beans when a file is updated?

Answer (score 0):

the best way for refresh your beans is add this scope "@RefreshScope" for example

Just add the @RefreshScope annotation on your refreshable beans and @EnableConfigServer on your main/configuration.

if you want to know more configuration https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html

regards!

Comment: from the docs, i have to trigger the refresh event. is there anything that auto refreshes on file update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `commons-configuration` library:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, you create a `PropertiesConfiguration` bean:

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.config.location", matchIfMissing = false)
    public PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration(
      @Value("${spring.config.location}") String path) throws Exception {
        String filePath = new File(path.substring("file:".length())).getCanonicalPath();
        PropertiesConfiguration configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(
          new File(filePath));
        configuration.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
        return configuration;
    }
```

The `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` is set as the reloading strategy with a default refresh delay. This means that `PropertiesConfiguration` checks for the file modification date if its last check was before 5000ms ago.

You can customize the delay using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy#setRefreshDelay`.

Comment: how to do it for the list of files in the xml? additionally, the code doesnt work. is it using the latest 2.7 version?